# How to highlight certain days on a timeseries in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dateVec <- as.Date(c("08-01-2015","08-02-2015","08-03-2015","08-04-2015","08-05-2015"),format="%m-%d-%Y")

myData <- data.frame(dat=c(.1,.2,-.1,1,.1),
                     dates=dateVec,
                     indicator=c(0,0,0,1,0))

ggplot(myData,aes(x=dates,y=dat)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I manually altered the plot here to shade the area around the datapoint with the highest value, where 'indicator' = 1.

How could I create this shading in ggplot automatically? Ideally I'd like the shaded area to have width, even though the x value is categorical. I've played with coloring the geom_point objects themselves according to the indicator, and while that works it doesn't really pop visually the way I would like it to.

Comment: One way would be to add `geom_rect(ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, xmin = as.numeric(myData$dates[which.max(myData$dat)]) - .5, xmax = as.numeric(myData$dates[which.max(myData$dat)]) + .5, alpha = .05)`.